# How to convert Protobuf ByteString to an octal-escaped String in java?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

Could anyone please let me know how to convert protobuf's ByteString to  an [octal escape sequence](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=details-octal-escape-sequence) String in java?

In my case, I am getting the ByteString value as `\376\024\367` so,  when I print the string value in console using `System.out.println()`, I should get `"\376\024\367"`.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Normally, you'd convert a ByteString to a String using [`ByteString#toString(Charset)`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/ByteString#toString-java.lang.String-). This method lets you specify what charset the text is encoded in. If it's UTF-8, you can also use the method `toStringUtf8()` as a shortcut.

From your question, though, it sounds like you actually want to produce the escaped format using C-style three-digit octal escapes. AFAIK there's no public function to do this, but [you can see the code here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/java/core/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/TextFormatEscaper.java). You could copy that code into your own project and use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kenton Varda. Your code helped me to get the desired output. But I am having some issue when I pass "/200". When I pass "\302s\207", output is coming as "\302s?". Any help in this as well

Comment: @DineshKumarJ Sorry, without seeing a lot more code I really don't know what could be wrong.

Answer (score -4):

I have used http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.3.7/akka/util/ByteString.ByteStrings.html
You will see to method `decodeString(java.lang.String charset)`

else see to https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/18738

Comment: The question was about Protobuf's ByteString, not Akka's ByteString.